# How to link WordPress website to an external Laravel application?

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, laravel

I have developed a Laravel application that is currently being used by my clients. I am in the midst of developing a simple WordPress website to advertise my services and basically showcase what I do.

I'm unsure on what the best way is to link the two.

My domain is www.themacrocoach.co.uk

I'm thinking the best way to do this would be if the client logs in from: www.themacrocoach.co.uk/login

Which then automatically redirects to:
www.themacrocoach.co.uk/dashboard

Upon logging out, the user is redirected back the WordPress website:
www.themacrocoach.co.uk

The dilemma I have is how to set all this up? Currently my server only has the Laravel application residing on it.

Do I keep everything on one server or split them across two?

Comment: http://v2.wp-api.org/  Try it , it will help

Comment: Hi, thank you for the suggestion but I can't see how this can help me. I'm not trying to pass data or share anything between the WP site or Laravel application. I just need to somehow integrate the two so that the URL's work. As an example /my-foods will be a URL of the application but /about-me will be a URL of the WP site.

Comment: I would actually put the Laravel site on a subdomain, maybe something like `app.themacrocoach.co.uk` and add a simple login button to redirect to that.

Comment: Thanks James, I too was thinking this.

Comment: do you really have a need for wordpress? Are you just hoping to use it for the authentication part?
If the wordpress authenticates and sends them to /dashboard does that mean /dashboard needs to integrate authentication?